# Confused on a theorem 4.25 in Apostol’s mathematical analysis

Tags: functions, continuity, metric-spaces, compactness

In Tom Apostol’s mathematical analysis at page 82, I am confused about the proof of theorem 4.25

> **Theorem 4.25.** Let $f : S \to T$ be a function from one metric space $(S, d_S)$ to another $(T, d_T)$. If $f$ is continuous non a compact subset $X$ of $S$, then the image $f(X)$ is a compact subset of $T$; in particular, $f(X)$ is closed and bounded in $T$.
>
> *Proof.* Let $F$ be an open covering of $f(X)$, so that $f(X) \subseteq \bigcup_{A \in F} A$. We wil show that a finite number of the sets $A$ cover $f(X)$. Since $f$ is continuous on the metric subspace $(X, d_S)$ we can apply Theorem 4.23 to conclude that each set $f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $(X, d_S)$. The sets $f^{-1}(A)$ form an open covering of $X$ and, since $X$ is compact, a finite number of them cover $X$, say
> $$X \subseteq f^{-1}(A_1) \cup \cdots \cup f^{-1}(A_p).$$
> Hence
> \begin{align*}
> f(X) &\subseteq f[f^{-1}(A_1) \cup \cdots \cup f^{-1}(A_p)] \\
> &= f[f^{-1}(A_1)] \cup \cdots \cup f[f^{-1}(A_p)] \\
> &\subseteq A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_p,
> \end{align*}
> so $f(X)$ is compact. As a corollary of Theorem 3.38, we see that $f(X)$ is closed and bounded.

It is said that $f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $(X,d_S)$, yes, but the sets $f^{-1}(A)$ are not an open covering of $X$, because an open covering of $X$ is a collection $F$ of open subsets of $S$ and $X$ belongs to these open sets

**$X$ is subspace of $S$, $f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $X$, but it not always open in S**

If the theorem said that $f$ is continuous on $S$, I think the proof is ok, but it said $f$ is continuous just on $X$.

I am confused, please help me, where have I made a mistake?

Comment: Where did you see that $X$ has to be one of the open sets. If that is the case you don't need any other open set to cover $X$!.

Comment: Sorry you misunderstood me.I mean the open covering of X is a collection F of open subsets of S.   But $f^{-1}(A)$is just open in X,  not S.

Comment: Apostol finds a cover of $X$ by open sets in $X$ and uses compactnes of $X$ to get a  finite subcover. Then he applies $f$ on both sides of the inclusion to get a cover for $f(X)$ by a finite number of the sets $A$. I don't see where your confusion is. Why do you need $f^{-1}(A)$ to be an open set in $S$?

Comment: Because the definition of open covering in book.at page 63. Let(M,d),be a metric space and let S be a subset of M,a collection F of open subsets of M is said to be an open covering of S if S $\subset\cup$A,$f^{-1}(A)$is not open set in S,so it’s not an open covering of X.for example,[0,1)is open in [0,2],but it not open in R

Comment: Suppose $(U_i)$ is a family of open sets in $X$ which cover $X$. Then we can write $U_i=X\cap V_i$ for some open sets $V_i$ in $S$. But $U_i \subset V_i$ so the sets $V_i$, which are open in $S$, also cover $X$. Hence there is a finite number of them that cover $X$. Let $X \subset V_1\cup V_2\cup ...\cup V_n$. This automatically implies  $X \subset U_1\cup U_2\cup ...\cup U_n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x \in X$ and $y=f(x)$. Then $y \in f(X)$ which  implies $y$ is in one of the open sets $A$. This implies $x \in f^{-1}(A)$, so $X \subset \cup_A f^{-1}(A)$. This is what is meant by saying that sets $f^{-1}(A)$ form a cover for $X$.

Comment: Yes,but how you proof that $f^{-1}(A)$is open in S,remember f is just continuous on X,not S.

Comment: I think I now understand where your confusion is. Saying that $X$is compact in $S$ is equivalent to saying that $X$ is compact in its own right when  provided with the subspace topology. This can be verified from the fact that a set $U \subset X$ is open in the subspace topology iff $U=X\cap V$ for some open eet $V$ in $S$. Hence any open  cover of $X$ by open sets in $X$ has a finite subcover.

Comment: Now I understand !!,thank you very much!!